# webapi multiple methods in MapHttpRoute

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

Using route annotations in asp.net core I can do the following easily enough

```
[HttpGet("ByID/{id}")]
public int GetByID(int id)
{
    return 5;
}

[HttpGet("ByName/{id}")]
public string GetByName(string name)
{
    return "neil";
}
```

However, with the same methods in the controller how do you do it using the non-annotation way in the WebApiConfig file (i.e. .net framework), i.e. what do I add to the below to make it work for the above example.

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

As a bonus, can somebody tell me how I would have the same URL map to two GET items differentiated only by type, e.g.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
[HttpGet("{name}")]
```

where one is an integer and one is a string - in other words the same as the above but without having to specify two separate url segments (ByID, ByName)?

Comment: I figured out the first part, which is to make multiple MapHttpRoute calls and use the action to set the name. Dunno if this is the best way:
defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional, action = "GetByName" }

So the only thing, presuming this is right, is how do you have the same url just differentiated by type.

Comment: what you need are route constraints

Answer (score 1):

You can use route constraints to differentiate the actions for the same path.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/somepath")]
public class MyController : ApiController {

    //Matches GET api/somepath/5
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public int GetByID(int id) {
        return id;
    }

    //Matches GET api/somepath/neil
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{name}")]
    public string GetByName(string name) {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Note the default is string which is why there is none on the second action.

Comment: Thanks. So how is this done when annotations aren't in (i.e. non-core asp.net application) - do I add a constraint in the MapHttpRoute method with a specifiction 'action?

Comment: @NeilWalker is this for core or web api 2